# Error handling in PySpark reading in non existent files

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark

I have a massive list of directories and files to potentially read from. However some of them may not actually exist which is not a problem - I would simply ignore any error - using a try method. Is there a way I can allow this in PySpark.

Here is the returned error message:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:
```

I am building the series of files to look at with the following:

```
scI = sc.textFile(",".join(paths))
```

where paths is a list of paths to possible files. Now I could check the file system and see if they exist, but is there a more elegent way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
for f in file_list:
   Try:
       read_file(f)
   except org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException:
       deal_with_absent_file(f)
```

Comment: I could do this with the standard os.path.isfile(fname), is there a way that I can handle this within the textFile call?